# Programmatically fill out an existing fillable PDF file with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, pdf-generation

Could anyone recommend an open-source library or gem for Ruby on Rails that could programmatically fill out an existing fillable PDF file?

After an extensive search I haven't been able to find much, other than the [pdf-forms](https://github.com/jkraemer/pdf-forms) gem, which uses [pdftk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/). Unfortunately, pdftk does not work on RHEL/CentOS 7 or other latest linux platforms, which leaves me looking for alternatives.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout PDF-Stamper at https://github.com/jaywhy/pdf-stamper. It might be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I have since created my own Ruby gem to solve this problem:

https://github.com/vkononov/fillable-pdf